# The app needs word wrapping!

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, android-app

It's time for an eye test! Point your Android app toward [this answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/9357/5573), or, here's a screenshot:

[image]

I'm using a HTC One running Android 4.4.2 and app version 1.0.26, and it needs some word wrapping!

Comment: Why not edit and format the link as one word? I don't think there's real case of so many characters without a space, unless a link or code, both can be formatted as such.

Comment: That link is wrapped for me on my phone (Huawei ascend g510)

Comment: @ShadowWizard It does need editing, but there is a real case right there. And even if it should be edited, the app should _probably_ be able to handle this elegantly.

Comment: @Howlin Huh. Maybe it's device specific.

Comment: Wrapping fine in iOS app, by the way. :)

Comment: I can confirm this issue on Nexus 5. This is clearly a use case which needs fixed. What if someone encounters this and doesn't have the rights to edit it? Plus it wraps on the desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoa, that looks ridiculous! Fixed in the next build (1.0.27), here's what it'll look like:

[image]

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at how it renders in the iOS app, which in my opinion is better than even the improved android solution. On the iOS app the link wraps as needed so you can read the whole url

Comment: @mhlester Yes, sadly that's out of my control. The state of `WebView`s on Android is a complete mess, and it doesn't make sense to fight it or try to hack things into it.

Comment: lol, fair enough ;)

Comment: Will it display that way now even on devices it was already working on?

Comment: @Howlin That is a fantastic question. It all depends on the device's version of the `WebView` handler. On 4.4+ devices it should look like my screenshot, I would assume older versions will stay the way they are but I can't be sure since none of my <4.4 (when Android used a different rendering engine) correctly handled it.